When assessing significance of identification variables (e.g., race) after applying a regression model, is it correct to use a Bonferroni adjustment?
I am building a regression model to assess whether being a member of any particular race (compared to the control group, which is White) is associated with a statistically significant loan application outcome at a bank after controlling for credit factors.
For example, I build a logistic regression model with the response variable being whether the loan was approved (a 0/1 indicator) and predictor variables such as credit score, loan to value ratio, etc. The idea is to first build a good model to predict approvals/denials and then add the race variable to the model to see if any category is significant (which would warrant further inspection such as file reviews).
Let's say the race variable has six total categories with the following p-values.

White: reference level
African American: 0.043
American Indian: 0.031
Asian: 0.293
Hispanic: 0.019
Unknown: 0.762

If I just use the standard 0.05 significance level, then I have three potentially problematic categories: African American, American Indian, and Hispanic.
However, I apply a Bonferroni adjustment to the significance level; since there are five comparisons to the reference level, the Bonferroni-adjusted significance level is 0.01. With this new significance level, there are no longer any significant categories.
My question is whether this is an appropriate use of the multiple comparison adjustment. I am familiar with its general usage but have not seen it applied to regressions in this manner, especially in my field where people typically just go with the basic 0.05 significance level without adjustment.

Because your stated question concerns "characteristics such as race," it sounds like you ought to be testing the model with race against the model without race using an F-test or the equivalent: that helps you decide whether race (no matter what it might be) is related to the outcome. The p-values you quote are for tests of five categories against the reference--but that answers a different question.

I wrote it that way because we also look at sex and age, but I figured it would be easier if I limited the scope of my question to race. I am not trying to find out whether race as a whole is significant in the model, but rather whether being a member of any particular race is associated with a statistically significant negative outcome after controlling for credit factors. I will edit the OP to be clearer about this.

Thanks--but that seems vague.  What exactly does it mean for a "particular race ... to be associated"?  Are you attempting, say, to compare each race to an average of all other races?  Or are you (as is standard in US anti-discrimination law) to compare races to a reference group, such as Whites?  Or are you trying to determine whether including race as a factor yields a significant improvement in the model?  (Or something else?)  These are all distinct questions that are tested differently.

Comparing race to Whites as a reference group (my job relates to ECOA and anti-discrimination as you guessed).

It sounds like you then have multiple but not independent hypotheses: namely, for each of four protected groups ("unknown" doesn't count), do they have a harder time getting loans compared to Whites? The alternative hypotheses are all one-sided, too. If you're quoting p-values from regression software output, they're for the two-sided tests. A lot is going on here, so it's crucial that you decide on the hypotheses to test before dredging through the data, lest you lose power and/or be accused of HARKing. That's why I warmly recommend focusing on asking your question as clearly as possible.
